# Цвет трека input опережает thumb, как исправить на JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, rangeslider

Вот пример того как background color опережает сам ползунок. Как исправить это, независимо от максимального и минимального предела input, без содания плавного перехода зеленого цвета в белый?

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('.slider--input');
let sliderValue = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end');
const sliderValueMoved = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end-moved');

sliderInput.oninput = function () {
  const inputValueNumb = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValue.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.style.left = `${8 + (this.clientWidth - 28) / 120 * (inputValueNumb)}px`;

}

sliderInput.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
  sliderInput.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, green ' + this.value + '%, white ' + this.value + '%)';
})
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider--body {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.range {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.slider--value-end-moved {
  top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
}

/* .slider--body > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
} */

.slider--input {
  appearance: none;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 60%, white 60%);
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Range Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider--body">
        <span class="slider--value-start">0</span>
        <div class="range">
          <input class="slider--input" type="range" min="0" , max="120" step="1" value="0" />
          <span class="slider--value-end-moved">0</span>
        </div>
        <span class="slider--value-end">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="range-slider.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('.slider--input');
let sliderValue = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end');
const sliderValueMoved = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end-moved');

sliderInput.oninput = function () {
  const inputValueNumb = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValue.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.style.left = `${8 + (this.clientWidth - 28) / 120 * (inputValueNumb)}px`;

}

sliderInput.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
  sliderInput.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, green ' + (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min) + '%, white ' + this.value + '%)';
})
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider--body {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.range {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.slider--value-end-moved {
  top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
}

/* .slider--body > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
} */

.slider--input {
  appearance: none;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 60%, white 60%);
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Range Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider--body">
        <span class="slider--value-start">0</span>
        <div class="range">
          <input class="slider--input" type="range" min="0" , max="120" step="1" value="0" />
          <span class="slider--value-end-moved">0</span>
        </div>
        <span class="slider--value-end">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="range-slider.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sliderInput = document.querySelector('.slider--input');
let sliderValue = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end');
const sliderValueMoved = document.querySelector('.slider--value-end-moved');

sliderInput.oninput = function() {
  const inputValueNumb = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValue.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.innerHTML = sliderInput.value;
  sliderValueMoved.style.left = `${8 + (this.clientWidth - 28) / 120 * (inputValueNumb)}px`;

}

sliderInput.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  let percent = this.value / this.max * 100;
  sliderInput.style.background = 'linear-gradient(90deg, green ' + percent + '%, white ' + percent + '%)';
})
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider--body {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.range {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.slider--value-end-moved {
  top: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
}


/* .slider--body > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
} */

.slider--input {
  appearance: none;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 60%, white 60%);
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Range Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider--body">
      <span class="slider--value-start">0</span>
      <div class="range">
        <input class="slider--input" type="range" min="0" , max="120" step="1" value="0" />
        <span class="slider--value-end-moved">0</span>
      </div>
      <span class="slider--value-end">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="range-slider.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```